# Finding lambda in Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics

I need help finding the value of lambda in this problem:

```
In a community of 1000 people, what is the (annual) probability of
5 births?
```

My book states that lambda is the average mean of all successes, but I don't know how to go about finding this. Could anyone help me find this? Please and thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $p =0.5$ unless otherwise stated. $\mu = n\cdot p = 1,000\cdot 0.5 = 500 \Rightarrow P(x=5) = \dfrac{500^{5}\cdot e^{-500}}{5!} \approx 0.0001$

Comment: why is $p$ = 0.5?

Comment: @Pedro I guess it depends on the community

Comment: I am unable to get 0.0001, I am repeatedly getting 0.0000. Any insight as to why?

Comment: I find taking $p = 0.5$ not so obvious to be honest. So you assume that you do 1000 trials with a probability of 0.5, on average every time step?

Comment: I will accept your answer, because it seems correct but, the website in which I give that answer still tells me it's wrong.

Comment: Does it say what the answer should be?

Comment: It does not say what it should be.

Comment: If I am doing this correct: (1000*0.005)=5 then ((5^5)*(e^(-5)))/(5!)? Which gives me 0.1754 which is also incorrect.

Comment: I think BRICS-Fan is correct and that $p$ should be assumed indeed 0.5 . You assume you have $0.5$ births "on average" for each person. Quite a high assumption though, but I guess he is right.